# bottom navigation view selected item doen't refresh on locale change

Tags: android, kotlin, bottomnavigationview

the selected item on bottom navigation doesn't change on locale change the text itself change, but the selected item still the old one before locale change, it should be the last element instead of the last one, the action of changing the locale happens on separate fragment and the navigation bottom exist on Main activity and there is no communication between them  I tried to override onConfigurationChange method, on it doesn't get called, what is the best practice to do that.

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean by

> it should be the last element instead of the last one

Here are few things to consider:

1. Bottom Navigation View can save its states (in your case, the selected item) when the configuration change.
2. onConfigurationChanged only called when your activity is running (in the foreground) and you have to add `android:configChanges` attribute with a value that represents the configuration you want to handle in the appropriate `<activity>` element in your manifest file. More info about the values you can specify is [here](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/runtime-changes#HandlingTheChange).
3. You should use ViewModel to handle configuration changes.